# Visual Studio WebBrowser renders webpage differently than IE

Tags: html, visual-studio, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to use the `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser` component in my Windows Forms application, but the (JS and CSS) animations don't get applied to the WebBrowser.

I know the WebBrowser component is based of off your computer's Internet Explorer version, and opening the HTML file directly in IE works just as well as Chrome. I also checked that the WebBrowser didn't use an *old* version of IE - it's IE11, using JavaScript version 13, just as the version of IE in the gif.

[Codepen containing the HTML code](https://codepen.io/iversen/pen/MXvZgZ)

[image: [left] C# Application. [Middle] Internet Explorer. [Right] Chrome]

What could cause this to happen? Cutting down on all the JS, leaving only HTML and CSS still gives me the same result, and I figure; if it works in IE, it should work in the WebBrowser as well, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the header `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` in the `<head>` tag of the HTML document.

*Source; [Web Browser Control & Specifying the IE Version](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version)*